# AngularJS - How to propagate event to a nested template?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to build a website which has the following flow.
`Index.html` -> `content.html`(partial rendered by `ng-view`) -> `wizard.html` (`sub-view` nested inside content and rendered by using 'ng-include').

The idea is, when a `user` is visiting `content.html` he has a `wizard` `link`, by clicking this `link` it triggers two things:

1. `url` changed to `#/sub/wizard`
2. Animation wrapped inside `directive` is activated causes the `wizard` to slowly slide in from top of the screen to the middle.

My problem is that when a `user` clicks the `wizard link` what happens is that only the `url` changes to `#/sub/wizard`.
Only a second click on the `link` triggers the animation to work.

I need to understand how to make `url` change and the animation to work in one click.

[My Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/UXz78GTB2sfV2e2LrnU4?p=preview)

**How does it looks:**

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

**index.html:**

```
  <body>
    <header>This is header</header>
    <div class="content" ng-view=""></div>
  </body>
```

**content.html:**

```
<div>
  <h1>This is Content brought to you by ngView</h1>
  <br>
  <a href="#/sub/wizard" started-animation>Open Wizard</a>
  <ng-include src="'wizard.html'"></ng-include>
</div>
```

**wizard.html:**

```
<div class="started_background">
    <section class="started_box">
        This is Wizard
    </section>
</div>
```

**My code:**

```
var webApp = angular.module('webApp', []);

//router logic
webApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'content.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .when('/sub/wizard', {
        templateUrl: 'content.html',
        controller: 'WizCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);

//controllers
webApp.controller ('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams) {

});

webApp.controller ('WizCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams) {

});


//directive
webApp.directive('startedAnimation', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem) {
        elem.on('click', function() {
            angular.element('.started_background').addClass('sticky');
            angular.element('.started_background').show().animate({opacity: '0.7'}, 1500, function () {
                angular.element(this).css({opacity:'1',
                    backgroundColor:'rgba(0,0,0,0.7)'
                });
                angular.element('.started_box').addClass('sticky');
                angular.element('.buttons_container').css({marginLeft: '280px'});
                angular.element('.started_box').show().animate({top: '20%'}, 1500);
            });
        });
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay found the way to do it, adding `function` calling to `onload` solved the problem
[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/vGYZRaqR1l9FNsKfeTB3?p=preview)

All I had to do is to add to the template controller:

```
webApp.controller ('WizCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.blah = function() {
                    angular.element('.started_background').addClass('sticky');
                angular.element('.started_background').show().animate({opacity: '0.7'}, 1500, function () {
                    angular.element(this).css({opacity:'1',
                        backgroundColor:'rgba(0,0,0,0.7)'
                    });
                    angular.element('.started_box').addClass('sticky');
                    angular.element('.buttons_container').css({marginLeft: '280px'});
                    angular.element('.started_box').show().animate({top: '20%'}, 1500);
                });
  }
});
```

and use `onload` :

```
<ng-include onload="blah()" src="'wizard.html'"></ng-include>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removed the url, make it look like this:

```
<a href="" started-animation>Open Wizard</a>
```

Comment: That's the problem, I the URL in the address bar to change. This is part of the requirement